# Height of a custom uitableviewcell

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a NIB file with a custom `UITableViewCell` inside. I don't subclass `UITableViewCell`. In my `tableViewController`, I load my custom `UITableViewCell` and put it in my `tableView`. But when the `tableView` is shown, the height of my cell is the standard `UITableViewCell height. Why? In my NIB file, the height is 311.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to implement

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

in your table view delegate.

Answer (score 1):

This method **heightForRowAtIndexPath** is valid only if we know the height values ​​for each cell. Often the custom cells have different heights and can dynamically create. If you do not know the height of the cell at the time of its creation, necessary to use additional methods.
For exemple: we know the content view height for each custom cell, we can call the method **reloadRowsAtIndexPaths**. In method heightForRowAtIndexPath we must return value from array. When we get new value for each cells we must replace value at index in our array and call method **reloadRowsAtIndexPaths**. After that we get new value for each cells height.

Answer (score 0):

If the height is the same for all table cells you would better do something like this:

```c
self.tableView.rowHeight = 125.0;
```

in your custom TableViewController `viewDidLoad` or `init` method